# Как из Range выбрать максимальное значение?

Tags: excel, vba

Проблемка скорее всего легкая но застрял....помогите кто чем может. Логической цепочкой- ссылкой-куском кода :)

Задача:
Есть масив данных вытащеных из SAP - *куча инфы\цена\дата*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужны самые последние цены для продукта

1) нашел сходство что самая свежая цена имеет самую высокую цифру в конце;

2) вытащил из \кучи инфы\последнюю цифру;

3) сделал Range котор опр максимальное значение и понял что в тупике(;

4) как перейти на следующий Range? - на скрине зеленый;

5) чтобы в результате к колонке К была цена - на скрине синим;

6) в колонке J могут быть пустые ячейки (когда макрос хочет взять последнее значение -показывается ошибка на которой он просто выполняет цикл дальше).

Куда копать дальше? 
\Ссылка на код: [введите сюда описание ссылки](http://depositfiles.com/files/bb808thcc)

```css
Sub ss()
Dim str, str2 As String
Dim lowmin As Integer
Dim w, lngRow As Long
Dim vValue As Variant
Dim rngCol As Range

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastrow
str = Cells(i, 1)

'copy paste last number from 1column to column 10

lowmin = InStr(12, str, "_", vbBinaryCompare)
On Error Resume Next
Cells(i, 10) = Mid(str, lowmin, 3)

str2 = Cells(i, 10)
   str2 = Replace(str2, "_", "")
Cells(i, 10) = str2

Next i
For i = 1 To lastrow
   

If Cells(i, 10) = blank Then

Cells(i, 10).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
i = i + 1
vValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Selection) 'Determines max valuein range
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Selection, vValue) > 0 Then
lngRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(vValue, Selection, 0) 'Determines in case the max
Cells(lngRow, 5).Copy
Cells(lngRow, 11).PasteSpecial
End If
Else
End If
Next i
```

Comment: Вот эта штука "...'êîïèðóåò ïîñëåäíåå ÷èñëî èç ñòðèíãà ...."  в приведенном коде что значит ?

Comment: Karl Hoffman, спеш? Вы и в жиз так разг? мож пис норм, а не куск слов?

Comment: "для куска модуля" - для какого куска? Что за модуль? При чем здесь пустые ячейки? Где  в примере пустые, которые мешают? Объясните толково задачу. И не стесняйтесь писать слова полностью.

Comment: "Алесксандр код который ниже копирует последнее число из 1 колонки в 10.

Comment: "vikttur мои извенения  больше так не буду и постараюсь яснее выражать свои мысли.=( Правильно заданый вопрос половина решения! Спасибо за Ваш интерес и заранее за будущую помощь в решении. Вопрос отредактировал надеюсь так будет понятнее. Также загрузил для удобства Ексель где  написан (код).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub LastPrice()
    Dim aData(), aRes()
    Dim lRw As Long, i As Long

    With ActiveSheet ' можно укзать любой лист'
        lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' последняя строка с данными в столбце А'
        aData = .Range("A1:F" & lRw).Value ' данные в массив'
        ReDim aRes(1 To lRw, 1 To 2) ' размерность массива результата'

        aRes(1, 1) = Val(Split(aData(1, 1) & "_", "_")(2)) ' извлекаем число в строке 1'

        For i = 2 To lRw
            aRes(i, 1) = Val(Split(aData(i, 1) & "_", "_")(2)) ' извлекаем число'

            If aRes(i - 1, 1) + 1 > aRes(i, 1) Then
                If aRes(i - 1, 1) > 0 Then aRes(i - 1, 2) = aData(i - 1, 5) ' запись цены'
            End If
        Next i

        If aRes(i - 1, 1) > 0 Then aRes(i - 1, 2) = aData(i - 1, 5) ' цена в последней строке'
        .Range("J1:K" & lRw).Value = aRes ' выгрузка результата'
    End With
End Sub
```

Макрос ориентируется на третий фрагмент текста в столбце A (*a_b_число*)

Comment: гениально! Спасибо огромное! Если можно вопрос: aData(), aRes() - обьявляется масив. но без концовки As Variant - что можно еще обьвлять таким образом? и где про это можно почитать?

Comment: *Variant* - по умолчанию. А почитать - наберите в поисковике "объявление переменных"